# Targeting only lowercase letters in text area

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to only select lowercase letters in a text area?

I want to change the color of lowercase letters in my text area to red and leave the uppercase letters as black.

Comment: I would use some Java Script code to insert `<span>` around all the lower case letter and then CSS to style the spans.

Comment: Are you trying to target a `<textarea>` tag? You cannot style the text in a `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: You can't style letters with CSS without wrapping them in an element, and a `<textarea>` element can't contain any child elements; so no, unfortunately not - unless you're able to use JavaScript, which is still a relatively complex (but required) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You won't be able to do that using a `textarea` element**. Because :

- you'll need to wrap your lowercase letters using JS
- strings in textarea are not interpreted as code but as text, so you'll have something like that "Hey, this is my text

What you can do :

- use `contenteditable` attribute on an element to replace your `textarea`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable
- use JS to replace your element content, wrapping lowercase letter (on `keyup` event).

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no method to do this using CSS.